# PHP Ajax Call Navigating to Action Page on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this ajax call in my php code that still navigates to action page. I want the ajax call to stay on the same page and only update part of the page. What I'm doing wrong here:

```
<form method="post" id="holderSave" action="student_add_scene.php">
            <h3> Save to Holder</h3><br/>
            <div id="cutfrom">
                <input placeholder="Cut from" name="from" id="from">
                <button href="#" onclick="captureElapsed('elapseFrom', 'from');
                        return false;">capture</button>
            </div>

            <div id="cutto">  
                <input placeholder="Cut to" name="to" id="to" >
                <button href="#" onclick="captureElapsed('elapseTo', 'to');
                        return false">capture</button>
            </div>

            <div id="savecapt">
                <input placeholder="add label" id="label" name="label"/>
                <input type='submit' value='Save' class='button'>
            </div>
        </form>




<script>
        $('#holderSave').on("submit", (function (e) { // catch the form's submit event
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({// create an AJAX call...
            var $form = $(this), url = $form.attr('action');
            var posting = $.post( url, { from: $('#from').val(), label:$('#label').val(), to: $('#to').val()});
            posting.done(function(response)){
                $('#holderSave').html(response); // update the DIV
                alert(response);
            }

        });
        return false;
        }));
    </script>
```

Comment: try by removing return false in the end. you are already using e.preventDefault() so i think return false is not necessary

Comment: @mohit thanx, but it has no effects on the outcome

Comment: that's not the correct way of using ajax! take a look at this link to learn how to use ajax => http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: also why `submit` the form when you really don't wanna submit it? you can easily write the whole action in the `click` event of a button or a link

Comment: @AminJafari — It looks correct. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @AminJafari — Because that's best practice. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a syntax error:

> ```
> $.ajax({// create an AJAX call...
> var $form = $(this), url = $form.attr('action');
> ```

You seem to be trying to treat the object literal you pass to `ajax` as a function body. It isn't, so you can't just write statements in it.

Since you make the ajax request with `$.post` later, `$.ajax` is entirely pointless. Remove that line and it should work.

---

Fixed code. Aside from the pointless half-a-call to .ajax, you had a bunch of syntax errors which I've fixed while reformatting it.

Use your browser's developer tools console. Use http://jshint.com/

```
// Remove pointless ( from before the second argument of the call to on().
$('#holderSave').on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Remove half a call to .ajax
        var $form = $(this),
            url = $form.attr('action');
        var posting = $.post(url, {
            from: $('#from').val(),
            label: $('#label').val(),
            to: $('#to').val()
        });
        posting.done(function(response) {
            $('#holderSave').html(response);
            alert(response);
        // Remove line with extra } here
        });
        return false;
    // Remove extra ) here
    });
```

Comment: Its not clear what should I remove, please post a complete code if possible

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a bit confusing! I'm lost in your code, I don't know what should I remove! It seems identical to my code here!

Comment: Thanks, that has done it! I can't see why this approach is better than binding to a click event!

Comment: Oh nice don't know that the submit event is fired before the real form submit... thanks you :)

Comment: @fareed — Because, as I've said more times than I care to count on this thread already, forms can be submitted without clicking on the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `submit` into `button` with `id`

   `<input type='button' id="save" value='Save' class='button'>`
2. Trigger click event for button, serialize the form data and post the data via `ajax`

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() { 

       $('#save').click(function(){ // catch the form's submit event
            var form = $('#holderSave');
            $.ajax( {
                 type: "POST",
                 url: form.attr( 'action' ),
                 data: form .serialize(),
                 success: function( response ) {
                   console.log( response );
                 }
           } );
       });
   });
   ```